# why tomcat is not as fast as apache for static page

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to benchmark apache tomcat with static page content and it seems way slower than http-apache.

I have tried below combinations but no luck.
Machine : 12 core , 16GB ram.
Tomcat 9 , java 8

```
 <Connector port="9080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
                maxConnections="32000"
                maxThreads="32000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="150" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Probably because your ISP is caching for Apache and not for Tomcat. There is a difference but it isn't 'way slower'.

Comment: am I missing something in configuration ?
which one is better to get something like 10K/second.

Comment: Use Apache if you can, even in front of a Tomcat. It gives you far more flexibility than Tomcat does.